# JavaScript modal dialog without user interaction that can't be closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have a page where the user can update a form by clicking on the name of an entity.  Think of a list of names, and the form with all the other fields (address, age, gender, etc.) updating with AJAX from the `onClick`.  How do create a modal dialog ("Please wait.") that prevents user interaction until the AJAX call has returned data?  I don't want the user to be able to click an <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Close</kbd> button.  They must wait!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) plugin.

It allows *blocking* interaction with the page or a specific element by adding an overlay on top of the page or that element. You can define a message and comes with a bunch of options to customize the look&feel.

You can for instance block a page when an ajax request is performed with:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $.blockUI({
        message: '<h1>Just a moment...</h1>'
    });
}

$(document).ajaxStop(function() { $.unblockUI(); }
```

Comment: This is a great plugin, and it's perfect for what I want! It can even block input on individual elements. I block before the AJAX call, and unblock on the AJAX callback. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.style.position = "fixed";
d.style.top = d.style.left = d.style.right = d.style.bottom = "0px";
document.body.appendChild(d);
```

That's the basic mask. After that you can add more stuff like a "please wait" box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a DIV over the entire contents of the page. Typically this is translucent to indicate that the user must wait. Sometimes there is a "loading" spinner on the overlay.